# ios share contact combined with mailto

Tags: ios, contacts, mailto

In IOS I would like have a mailto link with attributes to prefill recipient-address, subjectline, and messagebody. I assume this is supported just like in macosx? Any additional features IOS offers on this?

Within this process of opening a new prefilled email, I would also like to offer the user to add his personal (or other) contact details as a vcf card to the email.

I know the "share contact" button at the bottom of every contact in the contacts app can send contacts as vcf files in mail, but this route doesn't offer me prefilled email fields.

How can I combine the best of both worlds; prefilled email fields and share contact, from a webpage (without using additional ios apps)?

In the worst case, I'd have to ask users to share their contact, and copy paste the recipient-address, subjectline and body. I could copy all 3, with instructions (move subjectline and recipient-address from body to their fields), into the clipboard with JS, and just ask them to paste into the body.
Would that be supported?

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

iOS supports mailto for filling in subject field, message and multiple recipients in the To, Cc, and Bcc fields. The `from` attribute is not supported. ([Source](http://17.254.2.129/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MailLinks.html))

However, sharing a contact is not possible from the web browser. You'd have to write a native app.

Take a look at [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: The from attribute might not be supported to avoid changing of the sender, but an email received from ios does have a sender email right? When sharing a contact can you specify the subject line and body of the message. (notes?) Is it a normal email message you are sending, with an attachment, or a crippled email, an attachment with a note?

Comment: You can specify all fields and attachments from a native app. Look at MFMailComposeViewController (link above).

Comment: My question above was about using the default mail app, not a native one that I would write.    BTW, A non-native html webapp doesn't have special hooks to get to the contacts? Because writing a native app for this feature is currently outside of the scope. A webapp might be doable.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you cannot access contacts from the browser. Look through Apple's web app documentation for what you can and cannot do. http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/ipad/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html

Comment: Point taken. Now: the ios default feature 'share a contact via email' actually opens mail app, or only allows you to fill out an email and note within the contacts app, or no note at all? Meaning you cannot choose the content of the subjectline, and the note will be in the message body?

Comment: The share contact feature opens an email with the specified contact as a .vcf attachment. You can change all the fields.

Comment: I recommend that you get an iOS device for testing or use the simulator that comes with Xcode (mac only).

Answer (score 0):

ios user's can't attach their contact info as a vcf to a (mailto induced) email, but can send the vcf, as attachment to a true email (subject line is pre-filled 'contact' but all fields can be changed) from within contacts. If you need the user's contact info, ask them to send it that way, and instruct them what to paste or write in the fields, if important.
So the convenience of automatically inducing a new email from a browser link with pre-filled fields is lost on ios.